# Error in Turtle recursion

Tags: recursion, turtle-graphics

I'm attempting to use Turtle Graphics to make a fractal via recursion, but for some reason my code seems to not return the Turtle back to the origin. 
My code is as follows

```
public static void sun(Turtle t, double radius) {
for ( int i = 0; i < 360; i++ ) {
    t.forward( radius * .0174 );
    t.left( 1 );
}
    t.penup();
    t.left(90);
    t.forward(radius);
    //t.fill();
    t.pendown();
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    t.forward(2*radius);
    t.backward(2*radius);
    t.left(45);
}
t.penup();
t.backward(radius);
t.right(90);
t.pendown();
}

public static void fractalSun(Turtle t, double r, int level) {
int color;
if (level == 0) {
  t.color(255, 0, 0);
  sun(t, r);
}
else {
  sun(t, r);
  t.left(90);
  t.forward(r);
  t.right(90);
  t.forward(r * 2);
  t.right(90);
  fractalSun(t, r/4, level -1);
  t.left(90);
  t.backward(r * 2);
 }
}
```

The code compiles successfully, but produces this image:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss53C.png)

My goal would be for the turtle to return to the center of each 'sun' but something isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your 8-spoke loop leaves the pen at the center of the figure after each spoke.  At the end of the loop, starting at the center, you execute this sequence:

```
t.penup();
t.backward(radius);
t.right(90);
t.pendown();
```

In particular, you back up one radius; I think that's where you're getting off your intended point.  Drop that line, double-check your desired direction, and I think you'll be okay.

Comment: @willizen, I couldn't make this work as described -- could you?  This change retains the original problem of falling short on return to center and requires modifications to the other subroutine.  I belive that the problem is about more than direction, i.e. there's an `r / 4` unit of distance missing in the return trip calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Although the `sun()` method returns the turtle to where it started, the `fractalSun()` method leaves the turtle to the center of the figure.  So whether `fractalSun()` calls itself or `sun()` it has to make adjustments.  Here's an update fix with fewer changes (mostly deletions):

Change this final block of code in `sun()`:

```
t.penup();
t.backward(radius);
t.right(90);
t.pendown();
```

to be simply one statement:

```
// t.penup();
// t.backward(radius);
t.right(90);
// t.pendown();
```

Drop three lines of code from `fractalSun()` and change the arguments to the final function call:

```
public static void fractalSun(Turtle t, double r, int level) {

    if (level == 0) {
        t.color(255, 0, 0);

        sun(t, r);
    } else {
        sun(t, r);

        // t.left(90);
        // t.forward(r);
        // t.right(90);

        t.forward(r * 2);
        t.right(90);
        fractalSun(t, r / 4, level - 1);
        t.left(90);
        t.backward(r * 2 + r / 4);  // added a term to the equation
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Note: I simulated this using Python turtle so you may need to tweak my Java code if it's amiss.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thank you!

Comment: @willizen, I've updated this answer to be closer to your original in design with mostly lines removed and one calcualtion modified.